# How Do I Remove An Icon From The Menu Bar?

Tags: icons

I have an Apple laptop and I deleted an app but the icon still remains on the menu bar.  How do I remove the icon.  I tried dragging it to trash but it did not work.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: @HerbWolfe macOS, presumably.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to remove a random app - as we don't know what the app was, so we can't tell you where all its bits are hiding - is something like [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/), freeware.

There are other apps, free & paid, but this one has been rock solid for years.

The downside is for it to work properly, you will need to replace the app back in the Applications folder [either retrieve from Trash or re-download & install].
Then to delete completely, launch AppCleaner & drop the app onto it. It will find all related files & ask if you want to delete those too.

For a menu bar icon, you will probably need to reboot to complete the process.

No affiliation, merely a satisfied user.